# Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Run my Spring Boot application (sample program to post jason to Spring RESTful webservice) in Eclipse successfully. However, when I use the `mvn package` command to get jar file. Got the following message. Anyone could help.

```
: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controllerSimple' defined in file
```

ControllerSimple.java

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ControllerSimple {

    AddressList addressList;
    ControllerSimple (){
        addressList = new AddressList();
    }



@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String index() {
    return "Hello World";
}  

@RequestMapping(value="/crud_c_final", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<AnEntity> create_key(@RequestBody AnEntity anentity) throws SMException, IOException{

    System.out.println("request create received!");
    if(anentity!=null){          
        String key = anentity.getKey();
        String name = anentity.getValue().getName();
        String address = anentity.getValue().getAddress();

...
...
}
```

mvn package got following message:

```
   :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)


2016-04-12 00:41:16.113  INFO 16920 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplicationTests         : Starting DemoApplicationTests on WINDOWS-80KONH6 with PID 16920 (C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\springb\target\test-classes started by MyPC in C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\springb)

2016-04-12 00:41:16.114  INFO 16920 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplicationTests         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

2016-04-12 00:41:16.231  INFO 16920 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1197a46: startup date [Tue Apr 12 00:41:16 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-04-12 00:41:18.951  WARN 16920 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controllerSimple' defined in file [C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\springb\target\classes\com\example\ControllerSimple.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.ControllerSimple]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/util/HexDump

2016-04-12 00:41:18.968 ERROR 16920 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed



org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controllerSimple' defined in file [C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\springb\target\classes\com\example\ControllerSimple.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.ControllerSimple]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/util/HexDump

at       rg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

 at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

remaining error, show can not find the main class.

```
:[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin
:1.3.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project demo: Execution default of goal or
g.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE:repackage failed:
Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.example.De
moApplication, com.example.FileStorage, com.example.RandomGUID] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutio
nException
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your main error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'controllerSimple' defined in file [C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\springb\target\classes\com\example\ControllerSimple.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.ControllerSimple]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/util/HexDump
```

You should add more **Apache POI** dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It is almost there. Several error remain, but much less . I have edited the the post and put the error there.